# SoapUI throws Object reference not set: how to find reason

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

My SoapUI Pro program communicates with a wsdl. However, it throws an error. In the browser everything works fine (using the wsdl url and the desired parameters). The parameters I use in the SoapUI client are of the right type and filled in, so I don't understand the reason for the error. Is there a way to find out what is going on (more details) or can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Error:

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

SoapUI call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    
xmlns:tem="http://URI.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <item:GetSomething>
         <item:NodeID>1</item:NodeID>
         <item:VarA>false</item:VarA>
         <item:VarB>false</item:VarB>
      </item:GetSomething>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not test this webservice from soap UI like this.
Reason is, 
At your server, in your webservice implementation. It is expecting object type while you are providing string or integer tpe. Thats why it is giving you this error.

Wrap around these inputs in Objects then pass this request.

Thanks,
ambuj

Comment: Could you please let me know how to wrap the input as Object(String/int)

Comment: @kingAm Can you kindly let me know how to wrap the input as Object in SoapUI? I have run into the same issue and don't seem to be able to find an answer.